# PHP ezSQL and two connections to different hosts

Tags: php, ezsql

I'm trying to copy some data between different databases. For testing i used simply two databases both on localhost and everything worked fine but as soon as I try to establish the connection to two different hosts it doesn't work anymore.
My code looks like this:

```
$sourceDb = new ezSQL_mysql($settings['dbuser'], $settings['dbpass'], $settings['dbname'], $settings['dbhost']);

$targetDb = new ezSQL_mysql($settings['syncdbuser'], $settings['syncdbpass'], $settings['syncdbname'], $settings['syncdbhost']);
```

And the error message is this:

```
Warning: Error establishing mySQL database connection.
Correct user/password? Correct hostname?
Database server running? in ez_sql_mysql.php on line 89
PHP Warning:  mySQL database connection is not active
 in ez_sql_mysql.php on line 121
```

Is there any problem I'm not aware of, that prevents two connections to different hosts?

Btw. the connection information is 100% correct.. if I only use one connection everything works without any problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why I got this error. Switched to PDO and have no problems..

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for 3.08 version.

The problem is caused by the connect function. The Function get database name from constract . If variable is determined first time, it will not work for second or more.

Fistly; please open /lib folder

- Choose the file according to your database  ( etc. ez_sql_mysqli.php )
- find function connect( ....
- change it
  public function connect($dbuser='', $dbpassword='', $dbhost='localhost', $charset='')
  to 
  public function connect($dbuser='', $dbpassword='', $dbhost='localhost', $charset='', **$dbname=''**)
- find $this->_dbname inside function (connect). change it to $dbname.
  ( you can put  " if($dbname==""){ $dbname=$this->_dbname; }  "  before $dbname )
- find quick_connect inside class;
  change $this->connect($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbhost, true) 
  to $this->connect($dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbhost, true, **$dname**)
- it will work.